# VS2012 MSTest not generating trx with /logger.trx parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, trx

VS2012 MSTest utility suddenly stopped generating trx files. The same command was generating trx files till yesterday! It prints no. of tests passed or failed on console, but does not create a trx file.

Looks like some configuration got changed by system update.

```
MSTEST MyTest.dll /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Category1" /logger:trx
```

Any thoughts what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments you are using are arguments used by `vstest.console.exe` not `mstest.exe`.

`vstest.console.exe` is newer test runner and is the preferred way to run tests from the command line.

Comment: Agree with you, but the same command line was working with mstest couple of days back. Not sure why it isn't working now!